# How do I check if a ASP.NET MVC view contains a form?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms

I need to change the page formatting depending on whether the page (actually a layout template) contains a form or not. Is there any way to determine this in ASP.NET MVC 4?

Comment: By "form" do you mean a HTML form element?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you well, you can use ViewBag or ViewData or Session.

For example when you page was loading, you can set ViewBag data in get method. Then you can decide in view page what you want.

Also another way, when your page loaded in javascript you can post info of your page has form. You can collect this data in Session with a special key for current page.

As a result yes we can, I hope my answer enough. If not enough, I can help you if you explain well what you want really?